# Recursion binomial coefficient

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, combinations

I have to define a function that takes two numbers: n and k (n >= k) and returns the binomial coefficent of these two numbers.

```
#defining a function that computes the factorial of an integer

def fac(b):
    if b==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return b * fac(b-1)

#takes two integers and does the binomial coefficient operand

def combinations(n,k):
    result = (fac(n)) / (fac(k) * fac(n-k))
    return result

n=10
k=2

print(combinations(n,k))
```

This works well for small numbers, but when I take larger numbers such as 1000 etc, it doesn't work. 
It returns: line 5 in fac return b * fac(b-1) several times. 
Followed by: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.

Can someone explain why these functions doesn't work with large numbers and perhaps give any tips on what I can do to solve this problem? How does python deal with recursion and large numbers?

Comment: A much better solution would use memoization of doubles from the natural log of the gamma function, eschewing recursion and integers.

Comment: Please don't ask two completely unrelated questions at once.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Too slow? Recursion depth exceeded? Anything else?

Comment: I am new to programming and the function must be recursive.

Comment: @uselpa It returns: line 5 in fac return b * fac(b-1) several times. Followed by: RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: The math module has a factorial function. It is only one line of code to do the binomial coefficient with that.

Comment: @StefanGruenwald It says fac not defined.

Comment: If it has to be recursive... does it have to be Python?

Comment: @uselpa Yes Python3!

Comment: Why does the function have to be recursive? You can just as easily compute the factorial in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python limits the recursion depth to 1000 by default. You can change that by adding the following at the beginning of your code (setting the limit to 2000 in this example):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

To ask the user for input, try:

```
n=int(input("Enter n:"))
k=int(input("Enter k:"))
```

---

So here's the full code (just copy/paste it):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)

def fac(b):
    if b==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return b * fac(b-1)

def combinations(n,k):
    result = (fac(n)) / (fac(k) * fac(n-k))
    return result

n=int(input("Enter n:"))
k=int(input("Enter k:"))

print(n, k, combinations(n,k))
```

Comment: I tried my function with n=999 and k=10. Still recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: Works fine for me. What limit did you set?

Comment: You mean you didn't set the recursion limit to, say, 2000 as I showed in my answer? If so, why not?

Comment: I posted the whole code in my answer. Try to copy/paste it (entirely!). It works fine for me with 999 and 10.

Comment: Okay, first: It did work with both eval & int, so thanks for that. Second: You said python has limit the recursion depth to 1000, that means that it can take numbers less the 1000, right? I tried with 999, didn't work. When I used: import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000) everything worked great, but is there another way to make this work without importing? Thanks. @uselpa

Comment: With the standard limit of 1000 it will work for n slightly lower than 1000, not sure why. No, there is no other way in Python. Python's creator is not very fond of recursion, but since `sys` is a standard module this will work in every version of Python.